# FileBeat Service is not starting due to yml configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

This is my filebeat.yml file …
i am getting error :1053 whenever i am starting filebeat service.
may be some mistake i am doing in this file, please correct me where i am wrong.

```
###################### Filebeat Configuration Example #########################

# This file is an example configuration file highlighting only the most common
# options. The filebeat.full.yml file from the same directory contains all the
# supported options with more comments. You can use it as a reference.
#
# You can find the full configuration reference here:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/index.html

#=========================== Filebeat prospectors =============================

filebeat.prospectors:

# Each - is a prospector. Most options can be set at the prospector level, so
# you can use different prospectors for various configurations.
# Below are the prospector specific configurations.



  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
 paths:
- E:\ELK-STACK\logstash-tutorial-dataset.log
input_type: log
document_type: apachelogs
  # document_type: apachelogs



   #paths:
   # - E:\ELK-STACK\mylogs.log
  #fields: {log_type: mypersonal-logs}
       #- C:\Logs\GatewayService\GatewayService-Processor.Transactions-20170810
   # - C:\ECLIPSE WORKSPACE\jcgA1\jcgA1\logs-logstash.*
  # Exclude lines. A list of regular expressions to match. It drops the lines that are
  # matching any regular expression from the list.
  #exclude_lines: ["^DBG"]

  # Include lines. A list of regular expressions to match. It exports the lines that are
  # matching any regular expression from the list.
  #include_lines: ["^ERR", "^WARN"]

  # Exclude files. A list of regular expressions to match. Filebeat drops the files that
  # are matching any regular expression from the list. By default, no files are dropped.
  #exclude_files: [".gz$"]

  # Optional additional fields. These field can be freely picked
  # to add additional information to the crawled log files for filtering
  #fields:
  #  level: debug
  #  review: 1

  ### Multiline options

  # Mutiline can be used for log messages spanning multiple lines. This is common
  # for Java Stack Traces or C-Line Continuation

  # The regexp Pattern that has to be matched. The example pattern matches all lines starting with [
  #multiline.pattern: ^\[

  # Defines if the pattern set under pattern should be negated or not. Default is false.
  #multiline.negate: false

  # Match can be set to "after" or "before". It is used to define if lines should be append to a pattern
  # that was (not) matched before or after or as long as a pattern is not matched based on negate.
  # Note: After is the equivalent to previous and before is the equivalent to to next in Logstash
  #multiline.match: after


#================================ General =====================================

# The name of the shipper that publishes the network data. It can be used to group
# all the transactions sent by a single shipper in the web interface.
#name:

# The tags of the shipper are included in their own field with each
# transaction published.
#tags: ["service-X", "web-tier"]

# Optional fields that you can specify to add additional information to the
# output.
#fields:
#  env: staging

#================================ Outputs =====================================

# Configure what outputs to use when sending the data collected by the beat.
# Multiple outputs may be used.

#-------------------------- Elasticsearch output ------------------------------
#output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
 # hosts: ["localhost:9200"]

  # Optional protocol and basic auth credentials.
  #protocol: "https"
  #username: "elastic"
  #password: "changeme"

#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["localhost:5043"]

  # Optional SSL. By default is off.
  # List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications
  #ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/root/ca.pem"]

  # Certificate for SSL client authentication
  #ssl.certificate: "/etc/pki/client/cert.pem"

  # Client Certificate Key
  #ssl.key: "/etc/pki/client/cert.key"

#================================ Logging =====================================

# Sets log level. The default log level is info.
# Available log levels are: critical, error, warning, info, debug
#logging.level: debug

# At debug level, you can selectively enable logging only for some components.
# To enable all selectors use ["*"]. Examples of other selectors are "beat",
# "publish", "service".
#logging.selectors: ["*"]
```

Actually what i am trying to do is, i am trying to use multiple logs specifying "document_type", if i remove "document_type" then it works, but why "document_type"(as i see this depcreated in filebeat 5.5) or "fields" is not working in it.

please help.

Comment: Make sure that your yml field is properly formatted: http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/

Comment: @Val yes i have made certain changes and now it is properly formatted and again it is showing error while starting the service.

Comment: Output:-  {
  "output.logstash": {
    "hosts": [
      "localhost:5043"
    ]
  }, 
  "filebeat.prospectors": {
    "-input_type": "log", 
    "paths": [
      "E:\\ELK-STACK\\logstash-tutorial-dataset.log"
    ]
  }, 
  "document_type": "apachelogs"
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your config file.
The `filebeat.prospectors` keys wants an array value, but you are passing it a hash instead.

Plus, you have indentation problems.

This is a corrected version of your config file (without comments for brevity)

```
filebeat.prospectors:
-
  paths:
  - E:\ELK-STACK\logstash-tutorial-dataset.log
  input_type: log
  document_type: apachelogs
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5043"]
```

Comment: thanks it worked!! now i have one more question i have unstructured logs of my project authentic ...how may i apply grok pattern on it as it doesnt follow same pattern in it.